# When creating the IN on a procedure, how do you have two of the same inputs?

Tags: mysql, sql

**I am trying to obtain the average male and female salary per department within a certain salary range. To that end, I need to input two values I can input when calling the procedure.**

**I get this error:** Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUT p_avg_salary) BEGIN  SELECT      e.gender,     d.dept_name,     ROUND(AVG(s.' at line 1

**Here is the code:**

```
DELIMITER $$
USE employees_mod $$
CREATE PROCEDURE avg_salary_out(IN p_s_salary INTEGER, IN p_s_salary OUT p_avg_salary)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    e.gender,
    d.dept_name,
    ROUND(AVG(s.salary), 2) AS salary
    INTO p_avg_salary
FROM
    t_salaries s
        JOIN
    t_employees e ON s.emp_no = e.emp_no
        JOIN
    t_dept_emp de ON de.emp_no = e.emp_no
        JOIN
    t_departments d ON d.dept_no = de.dept_no
GROUP BY d.dept_no , e.gender
HAVING s.salary = s_salary
ORDER BY d.dept_no;
END$$
```

I have been moving code around but sort of at a loss. Any help would be extremely helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: why are you using a stored procedure for this?  what is your actual case where you want to use this?  how can you return a single average salary when you want the average per department?

Comment: Ysth - thanks so much. I am using a stored procedure because that is what the prompt required. End goal is to pull it into Tableu, so it seems I didn't need OUT part. My only question now is, does the INTO clause make sense for a similar situation? So I don't have to type out all of them in OUT for next time?